# position:relative not working in IE9?

Tags: html, css

Hello to all,

I am developing a webpage in which I am using a table to show the contents.
In the table I have a header part and a content part.

HTML:

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Address</td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Test Name</td>
  <td>Test Address</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2..</td>
  <td>Test Name1..</td>
  <td>Test Address123..</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Test Name</td>
  <td>Test Address</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2..</td>
  <td>Test Name1..</td>
  <td>Test Address123..</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Test Name</td>
  <td>Test Address</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2..</td>
  <td>Test Name1..</td>
  <td>Test Address123..</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Test Name</td>
  <td>Test Address</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2..</td>
  <td>Test Name1..</td>
  <td>Test Address123..</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Test Name</td>
  <td>Test Address</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2..</td>
  <td>Test Name1..</td>
  <td>Test Address123..</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Test Name</td>
  <td>Test Address</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2..</td>
  <td>Test Name1..</td>
  <td>Test Address123..</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Test Name</td>
  <td>Test Address</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2..</td>
  <td>Test Name1..</td>
  <td>Test Address123..</td>
 </tr>
<tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
thead tr   { 
position:relative; 
top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop); 
}
```

I want to make the header part static when the number of records increases beyond to a certain limit. This means it should not scroll down with records.

I am using the above CSS code but its not working. Can anyone suggest me a better way to do this? I am using IE9.

Thanks, 
Arvind.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`.

Comment: well i have already tried position:fixed.its working but header part is not displaying in a good way.

Comment: Do you have a live example we could have a look at?

Comment: Hello all.......well I am using same concept in two apps, one is running on windows and one on unix. Well the windows one is working good, only the unix platform apps showing the issue.